# Adding in-line comments to XML file

Tags: python, xml, dom

Say I have some random XML file with nodes like the following:

```
    <entry>
      <name>John</name>
      <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    </entry>
```

I would like to add an in-line comment as follows:

```
    <entry>  <!--He is a nice guy-->
      <name>John</name>
      <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    </entry>
```

I thought the following would do it:

```
all_nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName('entry')
for my_node in all_nodes:
  comment = flight_node.ownerDocument.createComment("He is a nice guy")
  my_node.appendChild(comment)
```

but I get:

```
    <entry>
      <name>John</name> 
      <last_name>Smith</last_name>
    <!--He is a nice guy-->
    </entry>
```

instead.

How can I get the comment in-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`appendChild`, as expected, puts it at the end. To insert it, you need to use `insertBefore`. This may not be exactly what you want, but

```
my_node.childNodes.insert(0, comment)
```

should get you close.